# Error " 'RNCWebView' could not be found " in Expo

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm new to React Native and I'm getting the error in the title.
" ERROR  Invariant Violation: TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'RNCWebView' could not be found. Verify that a module by this name is registered in the native binary., js engine: hermes"
Im using Expo ~49.0.13, expo-dev-client: ~2.4.11, react-native-webview: ^13.2.2 to build mobile app.

Is there a way to fix this bug? I have tried installing multiple versions of react-native-webview, but it didn't work.

Comment: Try to downgrade to  this exact version  `11.23.1` - https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/issues/2959#issuecomment-1549925312